# Python-Can or Pyserial in Windows

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, tkinter, can-bus

My company needs me to create a tool to read and send messages over a controller area network(CANBUS).  I've been successful in creating one in an Ubuntu virtual environment.

1. Can I use my Linux program in windows? (Written in python)
2. If I have to recreate it for windows, what would be the best coding language to interact with the bus and its hardware?
3. Are there any libraries that work well with canbus through windows?

Comment: Say what libraries you are using on Linux if you want some more detailed help.

Comment: What CAN hardware are you using?

Comment: Update: I'm currently using the "python-can" library for the reading/sending alongside "tkinter" for the GUI. Not a  lot of examples for python-can, might switch over to pyserial and see how that goes.  I'm using a VScom USB-CAN Plus for the receiving, and a Kvaser Leaf Light for the sending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1. Can I use my Linux program in windows? (Written in python)

Yes, you can. Python is SO agnostic. You will obviously need to install Python for Windows. Check which driver dependancies has the library you used for Python as you may need to install some driver in your PC.

## 2. If I have to recreate it for windows, what would be the best coding language to interact with the bus and its hardware?

No need to recreate it

## 3. Are there any libraries that work well with canbus through windows?

Same as on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about (3), but here's what I can say for (1) and (2):

#### Is it gonna work on Windows?

I don't know.
It depends on the modules you used.
Most of the time it is portable across platforms, but you might have to change some portions of the code.
If you mostly used TkInter and PySerial, it should work on Windows as well, but you need to give it a try.

#### What's the best language for doing this on Windows?

If you have a working version of your program for Linux, you should stick to porting it onto Windows, it shouldn't be too hard if what you used was standard.
Thus, I'd say that the best language is the one that already works on another platform.
However, if it happened that Python was definitely not suited for this program on Windows, then the best language would probably be the one you know best, as long as you're sure it provides the features you need.